# R subsetting dataframe on partial string match or separating or split

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, subset, string-matching

I am attempting to subset a dataframe by a partial string match. split and compare may also work since the string can be split by " | "
I believe that I used %in% in a past similar case but it does not work for this.
Any suggestions?

```
df <- read.table(text="
col1    cOL2      
1   '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47'
2   '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.4 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.4 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.64'
3   '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.64 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.78 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47'
4    '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47'
5   '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47'
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

```
df[which(df$cOL2 == 1 & df$cOL2 %in% '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19' ),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R functions, you could do:

```
subset(df, grepl('2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19', cOL2))
  col1                                                                                             cOL2
1    1 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47
4    4 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47
5    5 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47
```

Comment: is there a way to use the df[, ] way, I have many subsets with multiple filtering conditions, I can but I don't necessarily want to change all of them. Thanks

Comment: @Bristle yes this is base R code. Just do `df[, grepl('2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19', df$cOL2)]`. You can use `[]` and `subset` exactly the same way

Comment: `df[grepl('2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19', df$cOL2),]`

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(tidyverse)

filter(df, str_detect(cOL2, '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19'))

#      col1                                                                                             cOL2
#    1    1 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47
#    2    4 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47
#    3    5 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19 | 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.47
```

Holding on to `[]` you can do the following.

```
library(tidyverse)

df[str_detect(df$cOL2, '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.19'),]
```

Comment: is there a way to use the df[, ] way, I have many subsets with multiple filtering conditions, I can but I don't necessarily want to change all of them. Thanks

Comment: @Bristle: I've edited my post to accomodate your request.